# How to add an element in this ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

i've been trying to  make this work but how can I add a fourth element
in this ArrayList "hourCounts"?

```
public class HourCounts {

    private String[] hourCounts = {"One","Two","Three"};
    public hourCounts() {
      hourCount[3] = new String ("Four") ; // how do I write the code to add a 
                                           // new element that says "Four"?     
    }     

    public void countHours() {
      int hour = 0;
       while(hour < hourCounts.length) {
          System.out.println(hour + ": " + hourCounts[hour]);
          hour++;
       }   
    }     
}
```

Comment: That's not **an** `ArrayList`, that is an array. And Java arrays have a fixed length. Did you actually want a `List`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: this is not an Arraylist , this is a normal Array you cant add elements to a normal array after the instantiation of it

Comment: Also follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Thx for the help! i was wrong with my array and needed an arraylist. I've solved my problem.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

The following example of using `ArrayList` should help you:

```
List<String> hourCounts = private List<String> hourCounts 
                           = new ArrayList<>Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three"));
public hourCounts() {
    hourCount.add(new String ("Four"));
}
```

`ArrayList` is one of the most popular implementations of `List`. `List` is something different than an `Array` (`[]`).

Arrays are fixed length. `Lists` are flexible. Thus, when you know the amount of elements to store, you should use an array. (e.g. `String[]`). If you don't know the size or you know that size will change from time to time (by adding and removing elements) it's recommended to use a `List`.

Also, remember that in Java, `String`s aren't `char[]`. In fact, they store an array of chars in a certain field, but it's different from `C` or `Python`.

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays have a fixed length (at time of construction), you might copy your current array to add another element. Like,

```
private String[] hourCounts = { "One", "Two", "Three" };

public hourCounts()
{
    hourCounts = Arrays.copyOf(hourCounts, hourCounts.length + 1);
    hourCounts[hourCounts.length - 1] = "Four";
}
```

**But**, I think you wanted a `List` like

```
private List<String> hourCounts = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        "One", "Two", "Three"));

public hourCounts() {
    hourCounts.add("Four");
}

public void countHours() {
    int hour = 0;
    while (hour < hourCounts.size()) {
        System.out.println(hour + ": " + hourCounts.get(hour));
        hour++;
    }
}
```

Finally, please follow Java naming conventions (and don't name the class the same as a field in that class).

Comment: I think iterate over a collection can be improved not with respect to time complexity but from code readability